# how many variables a for loop can contain?

Tags: javascript

I finished a code challenge on HackerRank, and subsequently went to check some answers in order to see other's solutions and learn something new.
I bumped into a code base that contains the following code snippet.
thus arises the question, how many variables can a for loop contain, before the comparison check?

```
for (let i = 0, j = n - 1; i < n; i++, j-- ) {
    leftToRightArr.push(arr[i][i]);
    rightToLeftArr.push(arr[i][j]);
};
```

Comment: Why would there be a limit? How many variables can you have outside of a loop?

Comment: You can contain as many variables as you like. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#using_for_with_two_iterating_variables, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement

Comment: The for loop syntax is essentially `for(run this line once ; iterate if this line returns true ; run this line after every iteration )`, It doesn't matter what those 3 lines are. They can be anything as long as they are separate by `;`.

Comment: thanks @RickyMo ,
I know that they should result to an expression just never seen that syntax before. 
Thank you!